# Travis-CI build/link issue using xcodebuild on my project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, travis-ci, xcodebuild

**Problem/Description**

I'm trying to use Travis-CI xcodebuild mechanics to build/link and test one of my Github Swift 4.2.1 projects. Unfortunately I'm stumble over a link error during compiling an external used library (Spotify-iOS-SDK) - Everything else compiles just fine but this library for some reason throws a fatal link error each time. I've tried diverse configurations inside my travis.yml file but nothing seems to be working right now. The project builds and links fine on my local system using the XCode10.1 IDE (old and new build-engine). *I'm using POD composition stack for all of my used libraries*.

**Details/Logs**

Here some links to my project configuration including the travis-ci build history

[Github Project Sources](https://github.com/paterik/udacity-ios-aqoo/tree/development)

[Github Project Podfile](https://github.com/paterik/udacity-ios-aqoo/blob/development/Podfile)

[Travis-CI build history (current)](https://travis-ci.org/paterik/udacity-ios-aqoo)

[Local Build Logfile (current)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6970m8s8t2yez9x/build%20aqoo_2018-12-13T18-22-48.txt?dl=0)

**Travis Log-Output (screenshot)**

[image: Travis Log/Link-Error]

Comment: The local build command line executes fine. I've tested the normal **build**, the **build-for-testing** and **test** option (including the UseNewBuildSystem option). 

```xcodebuild clean build -workspace aqoo.xcworkspace -scheme aqoo -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s" -sdk iphonesimulator -toolchain XCode10.1 -UseNewBuildSystem=YES -configuration Debug CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NOcd```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ... I've to clean up my Pod directory and refresh local pod cache before my project vendor installation could start (using pod install). I didn't find out why this error occurred on travis and another local mac-system. It's a kind of weird / but now everything works fine.

```
travis.yml
    before_install:
      - ...
      - pod cache clean --all
      - rm -rf ./Pods/*
      - pod update
```